# Website Home Page redirects to a blank page

Tags: javascript, html, redirect

I have developed a website but when I access it by typing http://phalkefmcg.com it redirects to a blank page. But if I access another page like http://phalkefmcg.com/about.html it comes up properly. I have used Jquery and Javascript codes, but none of them have any redirect code. Is it a attack on my website? How can I resolve it?

Comment: attack :O share your markup ASAP.. ;)

Comment: Did you use any server side language for your index page ?

Comment: this is not a redirect problem but some JS problem

Comment: Agree with above, check the JS that is in your site.

Comment: I guess nobody from here will know what is the reason, except yourself to find out. Try strip down your code slowly to find out. You might want to start of with jscript include. :)

Answer (score 3):

I've digged out the problem to `http://remysharp.com/downloads/jquery.marquee.js`. It says:

```
// you're seeing this because you're hot-link a script that can be pulled from an 
// alternative source.  This script is only activated after a few months of trying
// to get in touch and requesting that you stop hot linking
setTimeout(function () {
  document.open();
  document.write('');
  document.close();
}, 2000);
console.log('Sorry, but you should not hot link files from regular blogs in case they do something like this. Best remove the hot linked files and you will be sorted again.');
```

So, remove the linked JavaScript file. (On line 118 of `index.html`)

Answer (score 2):

You have an errors in your JS. It appears to be removing all markup from your page. Open your browser's dev tools console to see the errors. In Chrome Is see:

> Sorry, but you should not hot link files from regular blogs in case they do something like this. Best remove the hot linked files and you will be sorted again. jquery.marquee.js:9
>
> Uncaught TypeError: Object # has no method 'infiniteCarousel' http://phalkefmcg.com/:20
>
> Uncaught TypeError: Object # has no method 'overlay'

**NOTE:** You really should post code here instead of links. This question has no value to the community once your page is fixed.